# Как изменить значение у обоих компонентов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Есть два компонента "My1" и "My2" , есть функция myFunction(). Компоненты не имеют общего предка и не взаимосвязаны. Обои компонента похожи и ссылаются на одну и тужу функцию. Вопрос как сделать так , чтобы при нажатии на кнопку любого из компонента значения менялись у обоих компонентов. То есть у обоих компонентов должно поменяться слово "Не нажал " на "Нажал" при нажатии на любую кнопку.

Вот первый компонент:

```
import React from 'react';
import Myfunction from "./myFunction.js" ; // здесь лежит функция

class My1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: "Не нажал" 
    };
  }
  NewStateOne = () => {
    Myfunction(this.state);
    console.log(this.state.name)
    this.setState({name: this.state.name})
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
        <button onClick={this.NewStateOne}>Click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default My1;
```

Вот второй компонент:

```
import React from 'react';
import Myfunction from "./myFunction.js" ; // здесь лежит функция

class My2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: "Не нажал" 
    };
  }
  NewStateTwo = () => {
    Myfunction(this.state);
    console.log(this.state.name)
    this.setState({name: this.state.name})
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.name}</div>
        <button onClick={this.NewStateTwo}>Click</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default My2;
```

Вот функция:

```
const Myfunction = (props) => {
  props.name = "Нажал";
  return props.name;
} 
export default Myfunction;
```

Я новичок в React буду рад любым идеям и критики.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить значение стейта из внешней функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171294/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: Я Вам уже ответил (на тот же самый вопрос) по ссылке выше, Вы передаете сам стейт в функцию когда Вам нужно передавать dispather (setState)

Comment: т. е. я нажимаю на одну, а текст меняется и на соседней?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov да именно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я нажимаю на одну кнопку, а текст меняется и на соседней:

Стейт не принадлежит кнопкам, он общий, и располагается в компоненте, который является предком всех кнопок *по дереву*.

Этот общий предок является провайдером контекста -- кладет свой стейт в контекст.

Кнопки используют `useContext`.